# Conditional Select() in Select()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a simple table 'Cars':

```
IdCar      |   Name     |     Id_Base
 1             Toyota          null
 2             Honda           5
 3             Ford            4
 4             Buick           null 
 5             Volvo           1
```

`Id_Base`  is a reference to `IdCar` field of this table `Cars`. So this is like a circular reference. I know it is weird, but I cannot do anything.

I have a `CarDTO`:

```
public class CarDTO
{       
    public int IdCar { get; set; }
    public int? Id_Base { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CarDto InnerCar {get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to project each element of table `Cars` to `CarDTO` if `Id_Base` is `NOT NULL`. That is I get a `Car` by its `IdCar` and fill `InnerCar` property of `CarDTO`.

So  the  wishful result should look like this:

```
new Car(){ IdCar = 1, Name = "Toyota", Id_Base = null},

new Car(){ IdCar = 2, Name = "Honda", Id_Base = 5, 
    InnerCar = new Car(){ IdCar = 5, Name="Volvo" }},

new Car(){ IdCar = 3, Name = "Ford", Id_Base = 4, 
    InnerCar = new Car(){ IdCar = 4, Name="Buick" }},

new Car(){ IdCar = 4, Name = "Buick", Id_Base = null },

new Car(){ IdCar = 5, Name = "Volvo", Id_Base = 1, 
    InnerCar = new Car(){ IdCar = 5, Name="Toyota" }}
```

What I've tried:

```
var cars = from car in db.Cars
     let innerCar =
         (from inCar in db.Cars
          where inCar.id_Base != null && inCar.IdCar == car.IdCar
          select new CarDTO
          {                                       
               Name = inCar.Name,
               IdCar = inCar.IdCar,                                       
               IdBase = inCar.id_Base,
               InnerCar = null
           }
           ).FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdBase == car.id_Base)
       select new CarDTO
           {                                  
               Name = car.Name,
               IdCar = car.IdCar,                                  
               IdBase = car.id_Base,
               InnerCar = innerCar
           };
```

But `InnerCar` is always null. I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong. Does anybody know how to project each element and create `InnerCar`?

Comment: Is `innerCar` (lowercase `l`) ever not null? Does `.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IdBase == car.id_Base)` ever return non-null? If the subquery always returns null, figure out why.

Comment: What version of entity framework are you using?

Comment: Honda is a brand of Volvo?

Comment: I'd suggest pulling all the data and then creating the relationships in memory with a recursive algorithm since what you really have is a tree structure in your table.

Comment: Shouldnt it be a list? ``pubic List<CarDto> InnerCars { get; set; }`` ?

Comment: But for just one level you really just need a self left join.

Comment: Why aren't you using a `Join`?

Comment: @KennethK. could you show how can I do it?

Comment: @juharr How can I do it?

Comment: @StepUp [All you need to do is search](https://www.google.com/search?q=linq+join).

Comment: I've withdrawn my answer since you've now edited the question with the correct tags. I still think you should be using a `Join`, but I don't have time to set up an environment to demonstrate how. EF joins should be documented well enough for you to see how to adapt it to your situation.

Comment: @KennethK. I am sorry, it's my fault.

Comment: @KennethK. You just need to map the entity object to the DTO object, as is shown in the question, and as was explained in the comment you got.  It has nothing to do with EF (you'd have the same issue with a LINQ to Objects query), although yes, that should have been mentioned in the question anyway.

Comment: @Servy I see now: I missed the `Car` in the question. I agree with you on the conversion.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  it is just an example not related with real life:)

Comment: @Servy could you show how the final query should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anybody know how to project each element and create InnerCar?

I don't. But I still think I can help you.

First of all please check out what a mapper library is if you don't know what it is. 'Automapper' for example. It can hugely simplify your life.
If you prefer not to use it you can set inner cars by simply using a dictionary. It would cost you O(n) and it is a simple code, which is a plus

```
      class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          var allCars = GetAllCars();
          var allCarsDtoDict = allCars.Select(a =>
          new CarDTO() { Id_Base = a.Id_Base, IdCar = a.IdCar, Name = a.Name }).ToDictionary(a => a.IdCar, a => a);
          foreach (var car in allCarsDtoDict.Values)
          {
            if (car.Id_Base.HasValue)
              car.InnerCar = allCarsDtoDict[car.Id_Base.Value];
          }

          var allCardWithSetInnerCard = allCarsDtoDict.Values;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<CarDO> GetAllCars()
        {
          return new List<CarDO>()
          {
            new CarDO(){ IdCar = 1, Name = "Toyota", Id_Base = null},
            new CarDO(){ IdCar = 2,Name = "Honda",Id_Base = 5,},
            new CarDO(){ IdCar = 3,Name = "Ford",Id_Base = 4},
            new CarDO(){ IdCar = 4, Name = "Buick", Id_Base = null },
            new CarDO(){IdCar = 5,Name = "Volvo",Id_Base = 1,}
          };
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

That line `inCar.IdCar == car.IdCar` seems wrong.

It probably should be `inCar.IdBase == car.IdCar`.

Your line would only get those with the same `IdCar`.

Or you wanted to write:

`inCar.IdCar != car.IdCar` - unequals instead of equals

Personally I believe this is easier to read:

```
var cars = (from car in db.Cars
          select new CarDTO
          {                                       
               Name = car.Name,
               IdCar = car.IdCar,                                       
               IdBase = car.id_Base,
           }).ToList(); //call .ToList() to fix possible EF errors by materializing all objects

cars.ForEach(x => x.InnerCar = cars.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IdCar == x.IdBase));
```